# Let $ p(x)=\alpha x^{2}+\beta x+\gamma $ be a polynomial

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ p(x)=\alpha x^{2}+\beta x+\gamma $  be a polynomial , where $ \alpha, \ \beta , \gamma \in \mathbb{R} $. Fix  $ x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $ \ S=\{(a,b,c): p(x)=a(x-x_{0})^{2}+b(x-x_{0})+c \}$. Then cardinality of $ S $ is

(a) $ 0 $,

(b) $ 1 $,

(c) $ \infty $

**My approach:**   I thought the option $ (c) $ is true. **But not sure . Any help ?**

Comment: In the df'n of S, presumably it is for all real $x.$ If  two polynomials , e.g. p(x)$ and $a(x-x_0}^2+b(x-x_0)+c ,$ have the same value at infinitely many values of $x$ then their co-efficients are the same.

Comment: That's some strange formula you've got there David

Answer (score 2):

We can easily find $a,b,c$ such that $p(x)=a(x-x_{0})^{2}+b(x-x_{0})+c$ for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, so $S$ is not empty.

To show that $\{a,b,c\}$ is the only element of $S$, note that a polynomial is the zero polynomial if and only if all it's coefficients are equal to $0$.

Therefore the cardinality of $S$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a(x-x_{0})^{2}+b(x-x_{0})+c = ax^2+(b-2ax_0)x+(ax_0^2-bx_0+c) $$

Comparing this with $p(x)$, you get that cardinality of $S$ is $1$.